# raspberry pi 4B git clone mysql-workbench build from source

Tags: mysql-workbench, raspberry-pi4

I have git clone the mysql-workbench from github and try to build it from source in raspberry pi 4B. But I stuck in the cmake ..

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:60 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindANTLR4.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ANTLR4", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ANTLR4" with any
  of the following names:

    ANTLR4Config.cmake
    antlr4-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ANTLR4" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ANTLR4_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ANTLR4"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

According the the error code, I try fullfit the requirement by
git clone ANTLR4, build it from Cpp version. Search all the Cpp folders, try to find out that ANTLR4Config.cmake and antlr4-config.cmake. But they didn't appear after the source build. Then I try the straight forward way: apt-get install libantlr4-runtime-dev. This does not work, too. How can I solve this? Do we have any way to make the find_package in cmake can find out the installed libantlr4-runtime.so file?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the libant4 libraries you can continue;

Try: sudo apt-get install